# Difference between predicate logic statements

Tags: logic

Translating these statements from predicate logic to English: are these the saying the same thing essentially or is there a difference?

$\forall x~(Fx \vee \neg Fx)$

$\forall x~Fx ~\lor~  \forall x~\lnot Fx$

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  Please show your attempt at translation and how you compare those claims.  People prefer to help those they see trying to help themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between these statements.

$\forall x (Fx \lor \neg Fx)$ is saying for all $x$ either $F x$ is true or $F x$ is false.

$\forall x F x \lor \forall x \neg F x$ can be rewritten as $(\forall x F x) \lor (\forall x \neg F x)$ and can be read as "Either $F x$ is true for ever $x$, or $F x$ is false for every $x$."

Answer (score 0):

Different. For example, if $Fx$ is “x is even” then the first statement is true for $\mathbb{N}$, but not the second, which would require either all natural numbers to be even or all not to be.